# PHP OOP Login/Registration design

Tags: php, oop

I'm attempting to create a login and registration system for my website, but I'm having trouble deciding on how functionality should be split up. For example should I have a User class that has login() and registration() functions, or should I have Login and Registration classes that contain a user object and the User simply contains data (id, username, etc...) without much functionality by itself? Do either of these seem like suitable OOP approaches, or am I way off base here?

**EDIT:**
Sorry that my question was so vague, I'll try to make it more specific. The User class that I currently have takes care of both logging in and registering. I've been told that each class should have one responsibility, so I'm not sure mixing those login and register into one class is good design. My question is when creating a class, specifically for a member system, is it better to separate functionality such as login, register and update into completely separate classes that have that have one purpose? Is one User class having a function for each of those purposes bad because it mixes too much functionality into one class?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your authorization system; both might be true or both might be false.

*Short Answer: Select one of them and continue*

If you want to write **Good Code**
Try to make it

- Adaptable
- Brief
- Consistent
- Correct
- Extensible
- Fast
- Flexible
- Generic
- Modular
- Reusable
- Stable under changing requirements

If you are trying to make your code even better, first of all; I suggest you to write your contracts (a.k.a. interfaces). After writing your interfaces (one for your data provider maybe, and one for service provider); try to write one for your login & registration system. And then; you will find the answer I hope.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any realization..

Just see realization of it in the top frameworks like Symfony, Zend, Yii, etc..

Or just use one of them. It is much better ;)

Comment: You forgot [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)!

Comment: Lavarel too of course)

Comment: and cartalyst/sentry2